# NODE JS - Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: node.js, api, undefined, push

I am having this problem sporadically in a node js application. It is very rare and always works with the same parameters, only occasionally this error occurs. I do not know what to do.

```js
async function run(sql, req, res) {

    var cod_cliente = req.query.cod_cliente

    hora_inicio = get_hora_atual_formato_sql()

    resp = new Object 

    try {

        resp.cod_cliente = cod_cliente
        resp.Sucesso = "OK"
        resp.unidades = []
        
        unid = []
        unid[0] = "RIB"
        unid[1] = "CTL"
        unid[2] = "BRA"
        unid[3] = "REC"
        unid[4] = "LDA"

        if (cod_cliente == null || (cod_cliente.trim() == ""))
            resp.Sucesso = "Erro - Parametro 'cod_cliente' nao informado"
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < unid.length; ++i) {
                
                unidades = new Object
                unidades.unid_fat = unid[i]
                
                if (resp.Sucesso == "OK") {
                
                    let cmd = `exec gm.dbo.sp_VerificaBloqueioCliente '`+unidades.unid_fat+`', '`+cod_cliente+`'`
                             
                    let q = await sql.query(cmd)

                    if (q.recordset.length > 0) {
                      if (q.recordset[0].bloqueio != 0) {
                        unidades.bloqueio = true
                        unidades.msg_bloqueio = q.recordset[0].msg_bloqueio
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        unidades.bloqueio = false
                        unidades.msg_bloqueio = ""  
                      }
                      resp.unidades.push(unidades)
                    }
                    else
                      resp.Sucesso = "CLIENTE_NAO_ENCONTRADO";
                    
                }  
                
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        resp.Sucesso = "ERRO: " + ex.message;
    }
    finally {
      grava_log('bloqueio_cliente_QA',sql,resp,hora_inicio);
      return res.json(resp)
    }
}
```

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: you've declared `resp` as a global variable - this might cause the problem if modify this variable in other places. Try to replace with `let/var/const`. e.g. `const resp`.

Comment: Thanks, but I call this variable only in this function. Do you think it can be that anyway? If not, what else can it be?

Comment: This code does not look like it could generate the error that you describe. Are you sure that this is what actually runs? It's hard to tell exactly what is going on without a stack trace. Also, have you tried to log the contents of `resp` just before the push() - assuming this is indeed the statement that is causing the error?